# how to compare backslash in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of strings that are read from a file say `['\x1\p1', '\x2\p2', '\x3\p3', ... etc.]`.

When I read them into variables and print them the strings displayed as  `['\\x1\\p1', '\\x2\\p2', '\\x3\\p3', ... etc.]`. I understand that the variable is represented as `'\x1\p1', ... etc.` internally, but when it is displayed it is displayed with double slash.

but now I want to search and replace the elements of this list in the sentence, i.e say if `\x1\p1` is in the sentence `"How are you doing \x1\p1"` then replace `'\x1\p1'` with 'Y'. But  the replace method does not work in this case! wonder why?

Let me explain further:
my text file (`codes.txt`) has entries `\xs1\x32`, `\xs2\x54` delimited by new line. so when I read it using

```
with open('codes') as codes:
    code_list = codes.readlines()
```

next, I do lets say `code_list_element_1 = code_list[1].rstrip()`

when I print `code_list_element_1`, it displays as `'\\xs1\\x32'`

Next, let me target string be `target_string = 'Hi! my name is \xs1\x32'`

now I want to replace `code_list_element_1` which is supposed to be `\xs1\x32` in the target_string with say `'Y'`

So, I tried `code_list_element_1 in target_string`. I get `False`

Next, instead of reading the codes from a text file I initialized a variable `find_me = '\xs1\x32'`

now, I try `find_me in target_string`. I get `True`

and hence `target_string.replace(find_me,"Y")` displays what I want: `"Hi! my name is Y"`

Comment: Please post the code you tried and tell us what you get and what you expect.

Comment: This worked for me :) 
`re.search(r"%s" %code_list_element_1,target_string)`
`re.sub(r"%s" %code_list_element_1,"Y",target_string)`

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at a string representation that can be pasted back into Python; the backslashes are doubled to make sure the values are not interpreted as escape sequences (such as `\n`, meaning a newline, or `\xfe`, meaning the byte with value 254, hex FE).

If you are building *new* string values, you also need to use those doubled backslashes to prevent Python from seeing escape sequences where there are none, *or* use raw string literals:

```
>>> '\\x1\\p1'
'\\x1\\p1'
>>> r'\x1\p1'
'\\x1\\p1'
```

For this specific example, not handling the backslashes properly actually results in an exception:

```
>>> '\x1\p1'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

because Python expects to find two hex digits after a `\x` escape.

Answer (score 3):

raw strings (those prefixed by `r` are very useful for backslash-itis.

```
In [9]: a=r"How are you doing \x1\p1"

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 'How are you doing \\x1\\p1'

In [11]: a.replace(r'\x1\p1', 'Y')
Out[11]: 'How are you doing Y'

In [12]:
```